# Removing Lists that Contain Sublists

Tags: python, list, sublist

Is there a way to remove lists from a list that contain the sublists?

Let's say that I have 5 elements from a to e.

I found all combinations from size 0 to size 5 below:

```
all_combinations = [[], ['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['a', 'd'], ['a', 
                   'e'], ['b', 'c'], ['b', 'd'], ['b', 'e'], ['c', 'd'], ['c', 'e'], ['d', 'e'], 
                   ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'e'], ['a', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'c',
                   'e'], ['a', 'd', 'e'], ['b', 'c', 'd'], ['b', 'c', 'e'], ['b', 'd', 'e'],                
                   ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 
                   'd', 'e'], ['a', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']]
```

Now let's say I want to remove some of these combinations that contain the sublists:

```
sublists = [['a', 'c'], ['c', 'd'], ['b', 'e']]
```

Is there a simple way of doing this? I should only be left with combinations that don't contain these sublists. I should only end up with lists where a and c are not together, c and d are not together, and b and e are not together.

EDIT: want to get output like this:

```
valid_combinations = [[], ['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['a', 'b'], 
                     ['a', 'd'], ['a', 'e'], ['b', 'c'], ['b', 'd'],
                     ['c', 'e'], ['d', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'd'], 
                     ['a', 'd', 'e']]
```

Comment: `[sl for sl in all_combinations if not any(set(e)>=set(sl) for e in sublists)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [sets](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set) to see if the complete list of items in `sublists` is contained within the sublist of `all_combinations`:

```
>>> [sl for sl in all_combinations if not any(set(e)<=set(sl) for e in sublists)]
[[], ['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'd'], ['a', 'e'], ['b', 'c'], ['b', 'd'], ['c', 'e'], ['d', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'd'], ['a', 'd', 'e']]

>>> _==valid_combinations
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
result = [item for item in all_combinations if item not in sublists]
```

Comment: I believe OP wants to exclude any list that _contains_ a sublist, this only excludes the ones that are equal to one of the sublists

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to use sets, in particular the function `issuperset` to check if a list contains all the elements of another. So, the following list comprehension returns all elements `a` of `all_combinations` that do not contain every element of any `b` in `sublists`

```
[a for a in all_combinations if all(not set(a).issuperset(set(b)) for b in sublists)]
```